# Why doesn't iOS have automatic garbage collection?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, garbage-collection

When developing with Objective-C on iOS, memory management currently must be performed by the developer.  Some of the other mobile platforms use automatic garbage collection to remove the need for managing memory.

What could be the reasons why garbage collection is not used on the iOS devices?

Comment: Misleading title (but correct tags). Objective-C has GC, but not on iOS.

Comment: a)subjective and argumentative b)just wait a bit.

Comment: I'd suggest that we have more control over what we keep around and what we don't. It does however, have `autorelease` on objects which is sort of garbage collection.

Comment: I think this question is valid. It's something that I'm sure other people have thought about and the accepted answer may provide some greater insight into how Obj-C and Cocoa-Touch work. Think about it ;)

Comment: "Manually?" Synthesizing and using accessor methods (or properties, which amount to the same thing) isn't all *that* much work.

Comment: @Sherm Pendley, it isn't that much work in a simple project. As the project grows in complexity and circular references grow -- something we take for granted as being "free" in all modern languages -- the nightmare of making sure your objects are actually retained at the right points can add a lot of project overhead. Plus, it's a bit difficult to debug since the object reference gets dealloced at surprising times.

Comment: On the other hand, if you're the type of programmer who does not make careless mistakes -- I've been told they're out there -- then it probably isn't "all that much work."

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem with garbage collection is that memory usage grows until it's collected, so there might be more memory allocated than necessary. That's bad for devices with restricted memory and no option to swap.

When the garbage collector runs, it scans the heap to find memory that's no longer being used, and that's an expensive process, that will slow down your device until is has completed.

Comment: **And** it does its thing *repeatedly*.

Comment: +1 for garbage collection process memory usage! Something that is not immediately thought of. You just assume garbage collection saves memory!

Comment: "...so there might be more memory allocated than necessary." Not might, *will*.

Comment: This is an over-simplification of garbage collection (GC). They're much more sophisticated, e.g. look into generational GCs (fairly standard), which rapidly collect short-lived objects while more long-lived ones get checked for collection more rarely. And that's just the basic idea, in practice there's many more optimizations and fine-tuning. Also see "incremental" collection which solves the "freezing" problem. Heck, they can even be concurrent. So far it's unclear to me why Apple went with ARC, the reasons they give seem overly simplistic. Refcounting has its own substantial overhead.

Answer (score 10):

At WWDC 2011, Apple explained that they didn't want garbage collection on their mobile devices because they want apps to be able to run with the best use of the provided resources, and with great determinism. The problem with garbage collection is not only that objects build up over time until the garbage collector kicks in, but that you don't have any control over *when* the garbage collector will kick in. This causes non-deterministic behavior that could lead to slowdowns that could occur when you don't want them.

**Bottom Line**: You can't say, "OK. I know that these objects will be freed at X point in time, and it won't collide with other events that are occurring."

Comment: And now with [automatic reference counting](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) you get the best of both worlds: developers no longer have to worry about retain / release of objects, you don't have a garbage collector process slowing execution randomly, and you still maintain fairly tight control over memory usage.

Comment: @Brad: Exactly! And if you really want to use MRC (Manual Reference Counting) you can. You can even incorporate files that use both systems of ref counting.

Comment: Your bottom line isn't really true. Depending on your garbage collector, you can have ways to force a collection, and also postpone collection. The latter is often done by creating a pool of objects beforehand then reusing them and avoiding any allocation during whatever critical operation you're doing, since GC is usually triggered through allocation. Note that this no-allocation strategy is used even in manual memory management, because alloc()/free() aren't exactly cheap either. Same reason UITableView reuses cells, etc., "don't allocate" applies in all performance-critical situations.

Comment: By the way, whatever memory-management papers I read, they keep mentioning the total resource-usage of reference-counting being higher than a good garbage collector, especially CPU time, though it's interspersed with program execution (atomic refcount changes on pointer updates). So it's questionable whether ARC gives "best use of provided resources." The determinism is more understandable, but then e.g. CoreAnimation runs in its own thread anyway, it shouldn't jitter due to GC or anything. I'd love to just jolt a GC on some complex app and simply watch what happens...

Answer (score 3):

The main reason is probably memory load and performance.  Reference counting has a smaller memory profile in that it allows the amount used by the application grow much more than reference counting.  Also, there is a performance issue in that when the garbage collector runs, other threads have to be stopped.  This is not really a huge issue on Macintoshes with fast multicore processors but could cause the UI to stutter on mobile devices.

The debate may be moot soon anyway.  Clang / LLVM has just had a new feature added called [automatic reference counting](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html).  This leverages the analysing capability to automatically put in the retains, releases and autoreleases so that the programmer doesn't have too.